# Some problems in the creation of MySql tables in a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, database, rdbms

I am trying to install a php script for the statistic on my server.

This script use MySql as database. The problem is that, when I try to install it, seems that can't create the tables in the database and give me the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 5
>
> Query : CREATE TABLE phpmv_a_category ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
>   auto_increment, name varchar(100) default NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) )
>   TYPE=MyISAM

The tables are created in a php file in this way:

```
$create['a_category'] = 
"CREATE TABLE ".DB_TABLES_PREFIX.'a_category'." (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) TYPE=MyISAM
";
```

Where is the problem?

Tnx
Andra

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual, `TYPE` is deprecated and was replaced by `ENGINE` in MySQL 5.5: documentation for [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's not `TYPE` but instead `ENGINE`

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/060f6)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ";" after `ENGINE=MyISAM`.